# My php code exec('ls -l') do not ls all files

Tags: php, exec, ls

I have a  `/Users/dele/Desktop/TestIOS/testPhp01/cms/test04.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: dele
 * Date: 2019/9/26
 * Time: 11:56 AM
 */

exec("ls -l");
```

When I run this file, there shows only one file output,

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.0/7.0.30_1/bin/php /Users/dele/Desktop/TestIOS/testPhp01/cms/test04.php
string(54) "-rw-r--r--  1 dele  staff   133 Oct  8 12:03 test04.php"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

but in my directory `/Users/dele/Desktop/TestIOS/testPhp01/cms/`, there have those files:

```
dele-MBP:cms ldl$ ls -l
total 48
-rw-r--r--  1 ldl  staff     0 Aug 20 16:49 1
-rw-r--r--  1 ldl  staff    42 Aug 20 16:49 2.js
-rw-r--r--  1 ldl  staff   165 Feb 18  2019 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ldl  staff   551 Aug 30 17:36 test01.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ldl  staff  1308 Sep  8 00:38 test02.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ldl  staff  1444 Sep 10 23:09 test03.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ldl  staff   107 Oct  8 11:56 test04.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using output param:

```
exec("ls -l", $r);
var_dump($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

exec("ls -l", $items, $return_status);

foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
  printf("%s\n", $item);
}
```

[Exec documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)