# php echo shell_exec not printing to screen

Tags: php

can anyone see why the following code is only printing to screen the URL's and not the results form the actual ping?

```
foreach ($websites as $url){
    $command = "ping -c 1 ".$url;
    echo"<strong>Address: ".$url."</strong>";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo shell_exec($command);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My php code exec('ls -l') do not ls all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280028/my-php-code-execls-l-do-not-ls-all-files)

Comment: shell_exec can only take one parameter though, this solution is for exec.. i tried  shell_exec($command, $r);   var_dump($r); and got error: Warning:  shell_exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Answer (score 0):

The `shell_exec()` function also returns null on error.
The `-c` Option requires admin-rights that your php script probably does not have. (tested this on windows)